# Null pointer exception when loading FXML through MenuItem JFX

Tags: java, javafx

Hello there I was trying to load a FXML through a MenuItem and although the operation I want to perform is done I get a null pointer exception. This is the FXML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="container" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="534.0" prefWidth="855.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="graphicInterface.ControllerHomePatients">
   <children>
      <MenuBar fx:id="bar" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="2.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="homeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Home">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="rHome" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Home Page" />
               </items></Menu>
          <Menu fx:id="View" mnemonicParsing="false" text="View">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="myCalendar" mnemonicParsing="false" text="My Calendar" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="mAppointments" mnemonicParsing="false" text="My Appointments" />
               </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="edit" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="mProfile" mnemonicParsing="false" text="My profile" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          <Menu fx:id="help" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help" />
            <Menu fx:id="logOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickLogOff" text="Close">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="signOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickLogOff" text="Sign off" />
               </items></Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="mContainer" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="118.0" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="40.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../images/UserProfile.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label fx:id="tName" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="182.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Name" />
            <Label fx:id="tSurname" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="220.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Surname" />
            <Label fx:id="tNif" ellipsisString="" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="255.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="DNI" />
            <ScrollPane layoutX="210.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="502.0">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="appointmentView" />
              </content>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </ScrollPane>
            <TextField fx:id="search" layoutX="422.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="118.0" promptText="Search" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="orderBy" layoutX="562.0" layoutY="40.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Order by:" />
            <Button fx:id="bPDF" layoutX="742.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickPdf" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Export to PDF" />
            <Button fx:id="bPrint" layoutX="742.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickPrint" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Print" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the controller of the fxml:

```
package graphicInterface;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControllerHomePatients implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane container;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar bar;

    @FXML
    private Menu homeButton;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem rHome;

    @FXML
    private Menu View;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem myCalendar;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem mAppointments;

    @FXML
    private Menu edit;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem mProfile;

    @FXML
    private Menu help;

    @FXML
    private Menu logOff;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem signOff;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mContainer;

    @FXML
    private ImageView image;

    @FXML
    private Label tName;

    @FXML
    private Label tSurname;

    @FXML
    private Label tNif;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane appointmentView;

    @FXML
    private TextField search;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> orderBy;

    @FXML
    private Button bPDF;

    @FXML
    private Button bPrint;

    @FXML
    void onClickPdf(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void onClickPrint(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void onClickLogOff(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Main.patient = null;

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));     
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) bar).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(new Scene(root));
        window.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tName.setText(Main.patient.getName());
        tSurname.setText(Main.patient.getSurname());
        tNif.setText(Main.patient.getNIF());
        ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Alphabetically", "Date");
        orderBy.setItems(list);
    }

}
```

The problem happens in the onClickLogOff method in the line were I set the scene. Why is the NullPointerException happening? Thank you :)

Comment: Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) bar).getScene().getWindow(); The getScene() is returning null but I don't know why I have been using this way to obtain a scene in other parts of the program and it was working fine but when it is does through a menuItem it returns null

Comment: Looks like `bar` must be null; can you check that with a `System.out.println(bar);` there (or use a debugger)?

Comment: How can bar be null if it is shown? I have added all this through SceneBuilder btw.

Comment: Whether it is shown or not has nothing at all to do with whether the field is null in the controller. It shouldn't be, given the code, but can you simply check it?

Comment: I have done the System.out.println(bar) and I get the Id and the style class

Comment: Weird. So is `bar.getScene()` null? (Not related, but why are you casting `bar` to a `Node`, btw? It is already a `Node`.)

Comment: You are right it is already a Node i have change it. I have check if bar.getScene was null and it is not know but I still get the nullpointerexception in window.setScene(newScene(root)

Comment: Wait. You said before you get the NPE on `bar.getScene().getWindow()`. Which is it?

Comment: Yes, but I was wrong sorry. The npe is in get window I have check it out sorry.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace in your question?

Comment: Ah, never mind... figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have registered your handler with both the `Menu` *and* the `MenuItem`:

```xml
 <Menu fx:id="logOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickLogOff" text="Close">
    <items>
       <MenuItem fx:id="signOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickLogOff" text="Sign off" />
    </items></Menu>
```

What happens is that when you choose the menu item, it fires an action event, causing your handler to be invoked. That replaces the scene. Then the menu fires another action event, invoking the handler again.

Since the scene containing the menu bar was removed from the window the first time the handler was invoked, the scene containing the menu bar now has no window, so

```
bar.getScene().getWindow();
```

returns null, and

```
window.setScene(...);
```

then throws a null pointer exception.

To fix, just remove the `onAction` handler from the `Menu`:

```xml
 <Menu fx:id="logOff" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close">
    <items>
       <MenuItem fx:id="signOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickLogOff" text="Sign off" />
    </items></Menu>
```